# Изменение стилей в Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

Здравствуйте! Хотелось бы узнать, как можно в Xamarin.Forms (PCL проект) создать в xaml стиль отдельно для Android, чтобы эти изменения не отображались на других платформах?

Answer (score 1):

Есть и другой путь: Необходимо просто создать стиль AndroidStyle и применить его в блоке OnPlatform

```
<ContentView>
    <ContentView.Style>
        <OnPlatform Platforms="Android" x:TypeArguments="Style">
            <x:StaticResource Key="AndroidStyle" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </ContentView.Style>
</ContentView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте собственный рендер для View в необходимом проекте.

Тут все исчерпывающие примеры:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/